# Googlefinance in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I use "googlefinance" in Google Spreadsheet Apps Script? The language is Js. These are my first steps in Apps script and I can't do it :/

Comment: you cannot use googlefinance in AppScript

Comment: @MattKing This is how I can get the daily rate of EURO against USD?? is there any command?

Comment: no there is no simple command like the way googlefinance works in a cell.  You need to search for how to use UrlFetchApp().

Comment: And I can't somehow pass the "googlefinance" command to the cell in the sheet's?

Comment: Hey man, did you find a solution eventually?